# Sed and PHP assoc array

Tags: php, sed, gettext

I have PHP code:

```
<?php
$vF = array('nazwa' => 'Nazwa', 'telefon' => 'Telefon', 'email' => 'E-mail', 'adres' => 'Adres');
?>
```

And I want to using sed change it to something like this:

```
<?php
$vF = array('nazwa' => _('Nazwa'), 'telefon' => _('Telefon'), 'email' => _('E-mail'), 'adres' => _('Adres'));
?>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the whole file, and in that particular format, then you can use `sed` with something like:

```
sed "s/\\('[^']*'\\)\\([,)]\\)/_(\\1)\\2/g" b.php
```

Otherwise, take a look at [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) for a full precision parser. You can read your PHP files, then use `token_get_all()` to find out exactly where the strings within arrays are, after which you can replace them with your desired string and render the modified source.

Comment: Probably need to make the comma optional, as the last array value doesn't have a comma. However, this change would break the regex, so you might want to also consider matching `=>\s*` before the array value.

Comment: Keep in mind this won't handle strings like 'Na\'zwa' which are perfectly valid in PHP. Also double quote delimited strings.

Comment: This will replace *everything* in the file. You need it to be smarter and only replace array values. (i.e. after `=>`)

Comment: @Ariel, it would be very complicated to make it bulletproof with regular expressions and sed. If that is the whole file, and in that particular format, it will work correctly. If not, then the PHP tokenizer will do a much better job.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=> )([^,]+)(?=[,;])/_($1)/g' foo.php
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat foo.php
<?php
$vF = array('nazwa' => 'Nazwa', 'telefon' => 'Telefon', 'email' => 'E-mail', 'adres' => 'Adres');
?>

$ perl -pe 's/(?<=> )([^,]+)(?=[,;])/_($1)/g' foo.php
<?php
$vF = array('nazwa' => _('Nazwa'), 'telefon' => _('Telefon'), 'email' => _('E-mail'), 'adres' => _('Adres'));
?>
```